# Revert Nullable Field to Required

Tags: google-bigquery

I used `.setSchemaUpdateOptions` and `ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION` to append data to my table that had several nonexistent/null values for REQUIRED fields. I was under the impression that it would temporarily relax the REQUIRED restriction. Unfortunately, it appears to have permanently changed all my fields to NULLABLE.

Is there a way to revert this change without replaying the entire table?

Answer (score 6):

You need to recreate the table, which you can do in place:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE dataset.table
(
  x INT64 NOT NULL,
  y STRING NOT NULL,
 z BOOL NOT NULL
) AS
SELECT *
FROM dataset.table
```

You have to list the columns and their types, along with the NOT NULL attribute for the ones you want to be required.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid recreating the table as it's rather large and would be an expensive operation. Is there a way to update all null values to empty strings/default integers? Alternatively, I've been considering another approach: Can I delete all null-value rows and then reinstate REQUIRED in my Terraform Schema? Once that is in place, I would append the delete data (I have a backup of it) with default values in place of nulls.

Answer (score 1):

As null values now exist in some rows in this table, you won't be able to revert the table to have REQUIRED CONSTRAINTS

Read more here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas

Relaxing a column's mode
Currently, the only supported modification you can make to a column's mode is changing it from REQUIRED to NULLABLE. Changing a column's mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE is also called column relaxation. You can relax REQUIRED columns:

Manually
When you overwrite a table using a load or query job
When you append data to a table using a query job
Caution: Changing a REQUIRED column to NULLABLE cannot be undone.

What BigQuery does very well is moving huge datasets between tables (note the costs) 
You can:
1. UPDATE the null values in your current table
2. Recreate a new table with the REQUIRED fields (if you want to stick with the name, you'll have to stop in a TEMP table as well)
3. Initiate a simple load job to migrate the data from the old to new table

Comment: I was under the impression that UPDATE was a very expensive operation that had a capped daily usage. Are you implying that I can update those specific rows and then change it to REQUIRED in my Terraform schema file? Or would I still have to recreate/copy the table? Also, can you elaborate on what you meant by option 3, particularly the simple load job?

Comment: In BigQuery, you are limited to 1,000 UPDATES per table per day. This doesn't mean 1,000 rows but UPDATE operations. The cost of the UPDATE depends on the size of the columns you address in your table.

You can execute a query and set a destination table for it so moving data between tables is not a big issue in BigQuery (depending on the size of your table of course).

You can recreate a table with REQUIRED constraints, UPDATE the null values in your current table, and load the current table entirely to its new destination.

Comment: With 1,000 daily operations, I'll be updating until I die haha, so I suppose I'll have to recreate the table altogether. That being said, so I know for future circumstances, would BQ allow me to modify NULLABLE -> REQUIRED if I removed all null values WITHOUT creating a new table? I use Terraform to specify my table Schema and each variable has a mode where I can set nullable/required. If I changed and deployed it as required, would it work?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this with a single DDL, but you can avoid creating temporary tables and pay twice for this fix.

Here is how you can do it:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `dataset1.table1`
(
  a INT64 NOT NULL,
  b STRING NOT NULL
) AS
SELECT
  COALESCE(a, 0) AS a,
  COALESCE(b, '') AS b
FROM `dataset1.table1`;
```

This approach ensures you only read and write your data once, and all the required transformations to replace NULL with a default value happen at the same time. This is important, because if you run N update queries per each column, you would be charged with reading the whole table N times.